# Why is the logical 'OR' not working on my second 'IF' condition?

Tags: function, if-statement, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I'm learning about 'if..else' and logical operators. I've written some code to help me learn as a go, here's the whole thing;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Function scope example</title>
  </head>
<body>

  <button>Press me</button>

  <script>
  
  const button = document.querySelector("button");

  function greet() {
    let name = prompt("What is your name?");
    alert(`Hello ${name}, nice to see you!`);
    let age = prompt(`${name}, how old are you?`);
    let favoriteFood = prompt(`${name}, what\'s your favorite food?`)
  if (favoriteFood == 'Fish fingers' || favoriteFood == 'fish fingers'){
    if (age > 16){
    alert(`You\'re ${age} and you eat ${favoriteFood}??`)
    alert("That's lame " + name + ", grow up.")
    } else if(age<16){
    alert('Yummy kiddo!')
    }
  }if(favoriteFood == 'Ham' || favoriteFood == 'ham'){
    alert('That\'s Ponyos favorite food too!')
  }else if(favoriteFood == 'Cheese' || favoriteFood == 'cheese'){
    alert('Cheese is good for the soul')
  }else {
    alert(`Cool, ${name}, that sounds yum!`)
  }
   
  
  button.addEventListener("click", greet);


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the part that's not working as expected;

```
if (favoriteFood == 'Fish fingers' || favoriteFood == 'fish fingers'){
    if (age > 16){
    alert(`You\'re ${age} and you eat ${favoriteFood}??`)
    alert("That's lame " + name + ", grow up.")
    } else if(age<16){
    alert('Yummy kiddo!')
    }
```

The first condition "Fish fingers" works when entered into the prompt and runs the following code depending on "age" but the second condition "fish fingers" does not. It skips to the "else" at the end.

I expected that when either 'Fish fingers' or 'fish fingers' were entered into the prompt, the following code would run but it doesn't.

Ive tried some reading it all again and playing with a sandbox which returned the result iIexpected. It was very different code but the way that the "OR" was used was the same.

Where am I going wrong? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reran your code, and your code works fine. Here is the output =>

**Bro, how old are you?18
Bro, what's your favorite food?fish fingers
You're 18 and you eat fish fingers??
That's lame Bro, grow up.
Welcome to Programiz!**

Perhaps, you made a typo in your input; or maybe you have put a double space or something. But the || statement is working as it should be.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I don't know what was wrong earlier but its running now as it should be here too. Thanks!